# "ShowTextAligned" error on iText7 in c#

Tags: c#, itext

I was testing the iText7 tutorial from here
(https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-3#2795-c03e03_ufo.cs)

This code is giving me an error :

```
canvas.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("CONFIDENTIAL"), 298, 421, pdfDoc.GetPageNumber(page), TextAlignment.
    CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 45);
```

error :

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Int32' to type 'iText.Layout.Properties.UnitValue'.'

How can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was doing this before the call

```
canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, 11);
```

changing it to the following avoided crash

```
canvas.SetFont(11);
```

Comment: It should be canvas.SetFontSize(11), but otherwise I can reproduce this strange side effect.

Answer (score 0):

The UnitValue class defines this constructor:

```
UnitValue(int unitType, float value)
```

So instead of passing integer into the method, convert it into UnitValue before you do that, for example:

```
new UnitValue (1, 20.0);
```

Passing 1 will create POINT, passing 2 will create PERCENT

Comment: Instead of passing magic numbers to indicate the type, you could also pass UnitValue.POINT or UnitValue.PERCENT

Comment: And even clearer is the usage of `UnitValue.CreatePointValue` and `UnitValue.CreatePercentValue`

Comment: I already tried this function .'UnitValue.CreatePointValue' .
But this time ShowTextAligned is not accepting UnitValue type variables because parameters are float type.

Comment: If you use the UnitValue.CreatePointValue function you need to pass in a float, not a UnitValue.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing same example / tutorial, and this post solved the issue for setting the Font Size. However, the example have the following additional code which also causes problems;

```
iText.Layout.Canvas canvas = new iText.Layout.Canvas(pdfCanvas,pdfDoc, page.GetPageSize());
canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT_COLOR, Color.WHITE);
canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, 60);
canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT, C03E03_UFO.helveticaBold);
canvas.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("CONFIDENTIAL"), 298, 421,pdfDoc.GetPageNumber(page),
                       TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 45);
```

With the Property.FONT_SIZE of the canvas.SetProperty() method causing exception:

> Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'iText.Layout.Properties.UnitValue'.

And the Property.FONT_COLOR of the canvas.SetProperty() method causing exception:

> Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'iText.Kernel.Colors.DeviceRgb' to type 'iText.Layout.Properties.TransparentColor'.

To resolve exceptions I either set the properties on the can object

```
 PdfFont helveticaBold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(iText.IO.Font.Constants.StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);
 canvas.SetFont(helveticaBold);
 canvas.SetFontSize(60);
 canvas.SetFontColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);
```

**OR** I changed the Property.FONT_COLOR and Property.FONT_SIZE values like this;

```
var transparentWhiteColor = new iText.Layout.Properties.TransparentColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);
canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT_COLOR, transparentWhiteColor);
canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT, helveticaBold);
canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, UnitValue.CreatePointValue(60));

//OR to create the UnitValue first
//var fontSizeUnit = new iText.Layout.Properties.UnitValue(UnitValue.POINT, 60);
//canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, fontSizeUnit);
```

Hope it helps whoever gets the same issues.